# Extracting single band from multiple band raster with PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, gdal, extract, multi-band

I'm approaching naw in the script and I'm trying to select many multi-band files from a folder and extract a single band from the file, putting everything in an output folder with the single-band transformed files.

Currently I concluded the following script:

```
 import sys, os

 output = "C:/../folder"

 layers =[layer for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()]


 for lyr in layers:
    if (lyr.type()==QgsMapLayer.RasterLayer): 

    cmd1 = "gdal_translate -b 1 "+ lyr.source() + "C:/..raster_input" + outputDir + "C:\..output" + lyr.name() + "test.ecw" 

    os.system(cmd1)

    cmd2 = outputDir + "C:\..output" + lyr.name() + "test.ecw"

    iface.addRasterLayer(cmd2)
```

But it does not work!

Answer (score 1):

Your path appears to be incorrect.  I believe you would want something like

```
"gdal_translate -b 1 " raster_input_dir + "/" + raster_filename + " " + outputDir + 
 "/" + lyr.name() + "test.ecw"
```